# Notify a python script that a process is done

Tags: python, subprocess

First of all let me just say that this is the first time i use python and i know nothing about parallel computing so my question might be a bit silly.

A friend runs some simulations on a cluster that runs on CentOS 5.5. For each run the program (tripoli) takes as input 3 files. First file contains data to be processed, second file is the output file (store results in this file) and the third file is the file that indicates how the workload will be distributed on the cluster( graphe.save ).

From one run to another the only thing that changes is a specific line in the input file. That is line 14.176. I stored all the possible values for that line on a different file. I'll call it isotopes file.

So my logic so far is. Open isotopes file. Take all data. for isotopes[1] open input file. write isotopes[1] to inputfile[14175]. close input file. run the program for this input file. Once you finished repeat for isotopes[2]. Each run takes about 50 to 60 minutes.

I thought polling a qhost command to see when node load is below a threshold ( 0.5 % for example ) in order to figure whether computation is done or not but it just seems bad practice.

I was expecting subprocess.call to behave the same way it does for something like this `subprocess.call("C:\Windows\System32.calc.exe")`(starts calc and halts there until calc is closed). I mean i expected that tripoli would start running and python would halt to that point until tripoli would reach the end of computation. But it does not. Once i hit run, tripoli starts as many instances as there are lines in the data file.

What am i missing here?

The code i have so far

```
import os
import os.path
import re
import datetime
import subprocess

def getLinesfromFile(filetobeOp, mode):
    with open (filetobeOp, mode) as temp:
      data = temp.readlines()
      temp.close()
return data


isotope = getLinesfromFile('isotopes','r')

for i, element in enumerate(isotope):
    runs+=1
    data = getLinesfromFile('inputfile','r')
    data[14175]="\t"+element
    tempElement = element.replace("\n", "")
    commandRunTripoli = "./run.sh inputfile "+tempElement.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]+".out    graphe.save"

    with open('tmt','w') as f2:
        f2.writelines(data)
        f2.close()

    subprocess.call(commandRunTripoli)

    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("Tripoli run #", runs, "with isotope::", element)
```

The run.sh file contains the following

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/TRIPOLI-4.8/CODE/lib/linux-intel-      4:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

\rm -f *.update graphe graphe.port last_simulation*
mpirun  /home/nefeli/.tripoli48/Exec/bin/linux-intel-64/static_tripoli4 -d   $1 -s NJOY -c /home/nefeli/.tripoli48/Exec/Env/t4path.ceav5 -o  $2 -p $3 -t bsd  &
\rm -f *.update graphe graphe.port last_simulation*
```

As kjp indicated the problem was that i was sending the process to the background (& in the .sh file). My friend uses ssh to connect to the server and run the simulations. A simulation takes time ( about 60 minutes ) and there are a lot of simulations to be done. So if the laptop powers off, the connection is lost and the process is killed. I thought that he could run the script using nohup and ampersand ( nohup python3 script.py & ) so that the process would continue executing even after connection was lost, but isnt nohup doing the same as & ? I mean if i run the command using nohup wouldn't i be sending the process to the background therefore causing the script to malfunction?

Comment: I don't see how the above code could engage in the behavior you describe.  There is only one subprocess call, and it's not in a loop, so how could it happen more than once?  Are you certain that the above indentation is correct?  Indentation is vitally important in Python.

Comment: Oh,  I messed it up when i pasted it here.I didnt notice it. It is correct in py file. Thanks for that

Comment: Is it possible that run.sh launches the tripoli process and then exits? That would explain the behavior that you are seeing.  It would be useful if you also posted the contents of run.sh

Comment: @dbw I would say yes. Duplicates in some files indicate that there are more than one instances running at the same time.

Comment: run your python script using screen or tmux, to allow `ssh` at will. Unrelated:  pass a list to `subprocess.call()` e.g., `call(['program', 'arg 1', 'arg 2'])`. Do not call `.close()` if you use `with`-statement: the purpose of the `with`-statement is to close the file even if there is an exception. Try to solve one problem at a time

Comment: so you're saying that `with open (filetobeOp, mode) ` will close filetobeOp once it gets the lines.Right? 
Ah.. file handling python docs, didn't make that obvious, however the with statement docs are pretty clear. Thanks!

Comment: `with` statement calls `file.__exit__()` method at the end of the `with`-statement (indicated by the indent). `with`-statement knows nothing about  files. It does not matter what you do with the file, the `__exit__()` method will close the file if it is not closed already.

Comment: Yes. Yes, I got that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the shell puts mpirun to background and returns immediately, if you want to wait until mpirun finishes its run, remove the & at the end.

```
mpirun  /home/nefeli/.tripoli48/Exec/bin/linux-intel-64/static_tripoli4 -d   $1 -s NJOY -c /home/nefeli/.tripoli48/Exec/Env/t4path.ceav5 -o  $2 -p $3 -t bsd  &
```

Comment: `subprocess.call()` waits for a command to complete and returns the returncode.  It is equivalent to running the first command you posted, without the insecure/dangerous shell=True.

Comment: Why would i need to add process.wait? I thought .call does that. Anyhow I tried it but no luck.

Comment: @dbw u r right, i just tested it, it does wait for the process to return.

Comment: @Silas - the problem is that your command returns immediately - see the & at the end - it puts mpirun into the background and returns immediately. subprocess cannot wait if your shell returns without waiting for mpirun.

Comment: Yes. That was it. Id never would have thought to look for something like this in run.sh. Thank you very much.